# How to lower step of x-axis in plot function of R?

Tags: r, plot

I'm plotting a curve with 253 pairs of points in `R` using `plot()`.Below `perf` contains these pairs of point. The X axis is between 0 and 1 with step equal to 0.2 when it's plotted. Even with increasing `pch`, `lwd` and `lty` the plotted points don't get more separated.
I want to lower step (fore example to 0.05) so that the points would be plotted farther from each other and the user can understand them better. How can I do it in `plot()` function of `R`? Is it possible to lower step of X axis or should use another function other than `plot()`?

```
plot(perf, add=F,col="black", lty=6, lwd=3, pch=19)
```

The plotted curve:
[image]

Comment: Please add a reproducible example.

Comment: Keeping the size of the plot the same, if you lower the "step" you would have to decrease the domain on the x axis.  Is this what you want?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, this is what I want. Please take a look at a plot I added.

Comment: @Pascal My code and plotted curve are now added to my post.

Comment: What range of values do you want on your x-axis?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't want to change max and min. It should be between 0 and 1, but I want to change the step to 0.05 or lower. So that more number would be shown in x-axis : (0, 0.05, 0.1,....,1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to suppress the drawing of the x axis during the `plot`, and then add your own custom axis.  This can be accomplished by adding `xaxt="n"` in the call to `plot()`:

```
plot(perf, add=F,col="black", lty=6, lwd=3, pch=19, xaxt="n")
```

Next, you can define a vector containing the number of ticks you want, and labels for those ticks.  Assuming a step size of `0.05`, you would have 20 points:

```
stepSize <- 0.05
xMax <- 1.0
numTicks <- xMax / stepSize
v1 <- c(0:numTicks)*stepSize
```

Finally, make a call to `axis()` to draw the x axis using the tick positions and labels:

```
axis(side=1, at=v1, labels=v1)
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I thought if I change step, I could see points by rectangle symbol since pch=19 should show points in rectangle. But I can't see rectangles still...

Comment: Use `pch=15` for rectangles, q.v. this [chart](http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/pchsymbols.php) which shows the various types of plot points available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `asp` aspect ratio parameter to `plot` function, which is equal to `y/x`, to adjust the plot ratio. 
If you like to control the axis labels you could use

```
axis(side=1, at=seq(0, 1, by=0.05))
axis(side=2, at=seq(0, 1, by=0.1))
```